# How to cancel UserNotifications

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsusernotification

How I can disable/cancel already setted notification?

Here is my schedule function.

```
func scheduleNotif(date: DateComponents, completion: @escaping (_ Success: Bool) -> ()) {

    let notif = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    notif.title = "Your quote for today is ready."
    notif.body = "Click here to open an app."

    let dateTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myNotif", content: notif, trigger: dateTrigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            completion(false)
        } else {
            completion(true)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For cancelling all pending notifications, you can use this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```

For cancelling specific notifications,

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { (notificationRequests) in
   var identifiers: [String] = []
   for notification:UNNotificationRequest in notificationRequests {
       if notification.identifier == "identifierCancel" {
          identifiers.append(notification.identifier)
       }
   }
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: identifiers)
}
```

Comment: Inside AppDelegate where we want to call this function?, inside `didReceiveRemoteNotification` or `application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage)`

Comment: This is for cancelling a scheduled local notification. It can be called from anywhere since `UNUserNotificationCenter.current()` is a singleton object

Answer (score 13):

The way **same** `UNNotification` is identify are base on the `identifier` passed when you create the `UNNotificationRequest`.

In your example above,

```
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myNotif", content: notif, trigger: dateTrigger)
```

You have actually hardcoded the `identifier` to be `"myNotif"`. This way, whenever you want to delete the already set notification you can do this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: "myNotif")
```

However, do take note that when you hardcode the identifier, every time when you add a `request` to `UNUserNotificationCenter` the notification is actually being replaced.

Example, if you scheduled a `"myNotif"` `request` set on 1 minute later but you call another function to schedule a `"myNotif"` at 1 hour later it will be replaced. Therefore only the latest `"myNotif"` at one hour later will be in the `pendingNotificationRequest`.

Answer (score -5):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31951293/1690717) you can cancel all notifications with the following code:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()`