# Using a switch to enable and disable local notifications (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift3, uilocalnotification, uiswitch

I'm making my first app, and one of the features is a to-do list. I have a switch that disables local notifications when it's off, and when it's on it's supposed to enable them for as long as the switch is on. I save the switch state using `UserDefaults`, the notifications do appear, however, **they don't repeat even though I specify that they should**. Right now I have the notifications set up to repeat every 60 seconds for testing but when it works it will be two days. How can I make the notifications repeat as long as the switch is on? My code for the switch:

```
@IBOutlet weak var switchout: UISwitch!

@IBAction func notifswitch(_ sender: Any) {
print ("hello")
    if switchout.isOn
    {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *), list.isEmpty == false {

            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "You have tasks to complete!"
            content.subtitle = ""
            content.body = "Open the task manager to see which tasks 
need completion"
            let alarmTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(60) 
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, 
.hour, .minute], from: alarmTime)
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: 
components, repeats: true)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: 
"taskreminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, 
withCompletionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            print ("hello")
        }

    } else
    {
        UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    }

    self.saveSwitchesStates()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you're using the wrong cancel API.

Instead of:

```
UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Try using:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```

That cancels everything for your app though.  If you want to do specific notifications, you can do:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: "taskreminder")
```

More info [can be seen at this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562912/usernotifications-cancel-swift3).

2 )

Now in regards to your notifications not repeating, even though you've set `true` when setting up the trigger, I see that the time you're setting up requires a match for `[.weekday, .hour, .minute]`, which means it'll repeat every day of the week at the same time.

Try passing **THIS** to `UNNotificationRequest` instead:

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Alright, I'll try adding that. But how do I solve the issue of the notifications not repeating?