# Cancel UNNotificationRequest

Tags: ios, swift, unnotificationrequest

Because `UILocalNotification` is now deprecated, I moved my code to the new `UNNotificationRequest` API.

It states: '**cancelLocalNotification**' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's `-[UNUserNotificationCenter removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers:]`

But it seems that it is not equal - while I could remove messages with `cancelLocalNotification` at any time (even they are displayed/delivered) it seems that `removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers` only removes undelivered notifications. That's really annoying.

So my question is: 
Is there a valid way removing notifications queued with `UNNotificationRequest` or should I just ignore those deprecation warnings?

Comment: see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562912/usernotifications-cancel-swift3

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik that question only mentions pending notifications as well and OP was looking for delivered notifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the `removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:)` function to remove already delivered notifications from the notification center. For more info, see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649500-removedeliverednotifications)

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4** and **Swift 5**

If you want to **remove all** `UNNotificationRequest` items, you can use:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```