# Cancel notification before presentation

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

Is it possible to have a short evaluation process happen before a local notification is being presented?

Depending on the outcome of this evaluation, I would then cancel/remove a potentially unnecessary notification.

Comment: Are your notifications time based ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UserNotifications cancel, swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562912/usernotifications-cancel-swift3)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I do not think so, as that answer states How to delete a registered pending notification. This question is more about When.

Comment: @Abdul91 it is all about removePendingNotificationRequests from the queue of notification. so it is related. If you have scheduled notification then it is in queue. if you don't want it remove it. there is no when

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a particular local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340664/delete-a-particular-local-notification)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Note that mentioning:

> Is it possible to have a short evaluation process happen **before a**
>   **local notification is being presented**?

Means that the notification status is *Pending*.

So what you should do is to call [removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649517-removependingnotificationrequest) and passing the notification identifier(s) to it that you want it/them to be removed.

You could implement it like this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["notificationID"])
```

and that should do the job.

Note that it takes `identifiers` as an array of strings, even if your need is to remove only one notification, you would need to pass an array containing one string.

Obviously, "notificationID" is the used identifier for your notification that you are using when you registering it (when creating the `UNNotificationRequest`):

```
// ...
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notificationID", content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

Comment: When are you calling removePendingNotificationRequests ?

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. But I guess this would require a background process to `removePendingNotificationRequests` without the app being active?

Comment: @Abdul91 based on the OP request, it should be depends on "short evaluation process" validation...

Comment: @Bernd you might be able to achieve it, checking the two methods of [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate) hopefully would be useful to your case.