# How to cancel or delete on my lock screen after seen UILocalNotification in swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3

How to solve this problem? Please help me.

I used the following code in my project, but can't delete notification.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0,  {

let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [String(self.chatRoom.getChatRoomID())])
} else {
// Fallback on earlier versions
}
var app:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications! {
var notification = oneEvent as UILocalNotification
let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo! as! [String:AnyObject]
let uid = userInfoCurrent["TeamChatRoomID"]! as! String
if uid == String(self.chatRoom.getChatRoomID()){
//Cancelling local notification
app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Have You try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951142/how-to-cancel-a-localnotification-with-the-press-of-a-button-in-swift)?

Comment: @ Ketan Odedra : See the above code i am using.

Answer (score 0):

To clear all the notification from notification center

**ios>10:**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter

**ios<10:**
setting application badge number to 0 should do the trick

But I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, as the question is unclear.